# How to revert a 'create_extension` statement in a Rails database migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

In a Rails 5 app with Postgres, I have this migration file:

```
class MigrateStuff < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    enable_extension 'uuid-ossp'

    # migrate stuff
  end

  def down
    # rollback stuff
  end
end
```

**My question is:**

Is it necessary/cleaner to revert the `enable_extension` call?

And if so, how?

I've tried `drop_extension` but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

In your `down` block you have to use

`disable_extension`

and revert the corresponding migration which will call the drop extension statement.

More info can be found at the [Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/579d3dc086d29c06753aaa655820f92ad0d48179/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L338)

Comment: `disable_extension` documentation https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter/disable_extension